# Disable button property not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, php

I have a button **Upload** where in file will be uploaded, But the requirement is when is selected a file and then press **Upload** button.The button should be disabled until the process occurs with complete validation issues.

The code i have written is shown below.

```
 <form id='FM_EmployeeUpload' name='FM_EmployeeUpload' method='post' action='new_S_EmployeeUpload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

 echo('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg pull-left" name="submit" onClick="DisableButton();" id="Upload" value="UPLOAD"/>&nbsp;');

  </form>

function DisableButton(){
        document.getElementById("Upload").disabled = true;
}
```

Now the problem arises with the **Browsers** when i do this task on **Firefox** if there is error in uploading the file Validation issues will takes place and it will work perfect.The screen shot is shown below.
[image: IN FIREFOX]

But the same code i run in **Google Chrome** No validation nothing will happen ony the button will e `disabled` some what looks like this.

[image: IN CHROME]

What is the main issue regarding the problem. Any help appreciated.

Comment: your input name should not be submit this is not a good practice.
Browsers add names and ids of form controls as properties to the FORM. This results in the properties of the form being replaced.

Browsers also may add names and id's of other elements as properties to document, and sometimes to the global object (or an object above the global object in scope). This non-standard behavior can result in replacement of properties on other objects. The problems it causes are discussed in detail.

A problem occurs when a form control's name conflicts with the a property name of the FORM object

Comment: Simple Unsafe Name Example

<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

Comment: your form is working correctly on chrome.

Comment: @shiva What's the solution now?